# Opposite sign of function value and odd number of roots

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a polynomial on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)f(b)<0$, then $f(x)$ have odd number of roots. I know by intermediate value theorem there exists at least one root between $a$ and $b$. But I do not know how to show $f$ have odd number of roots.

Comment: $f$ could also have infinitely many roots without any further assumptions, and then odd number of roots wouldn't mean much. Do you have other conditions you forgot to state?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur maybe the question is about polynomials, and then it is true , as i proved in my answer.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur. Sorry I forgot to mention f is a polynomial.

Comment: @infinity Yes. You are right. I forgot to mention f is a polynomial. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general, take for example the following function:

$f(x) = x $ in $[-1,1]$

$f(x) = -x+2 $ in $[1,2]$

$f(x) = x-2 $ in $[2,3]$

So $f$ has 2 zeros and yet $f(-1)f(3)<0$.

---

If $f$ is assumed to be a polynomial the statement is true and we can prove this by induction on the degree of $f$ , $n$:

for $n=1$ the statement is clear.

Assume the statement is true for polynomials of degree $\le n$ and let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n+1$.

By assumption ($f(a)f(b)<0$) there is a zero for $f$ in $[a,b]$.

Let's take a minimal zero for $f$ in $[a,b]$ we can do so because $f$ has finitely many roots , denote this zero by $c$.

So $x-c$ divides $f$ , $f(x) = (x-c) p(x)$ where $p$ is polynomial of degree $n$.

If $p$ has no roots, we are done.

Otherwise , we can continue and write $f(x) = (x-c)(x-d) q(x)$ here $d$ is chosen again to be minimal of the roots that are $\ge c$.Note that $deg(q)\le n$

Now $q$ satisfy $q(a)q(b) <0$ so by induction hypothesis  $q$  has odd number of roots. 
Now just note that the roots of $q$ along with $c,d$ are all the roots of $f$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ f$ defined at $ [-1,2]$ by

$$f(x)=|x| \text{ if } -1\le x\le 1$$
and

$$f(x)=1-3(x-1) \text{ if } x\ge 1$$
It is continuous and has only two roots.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true even for polynomials. In fact consider the example :
$$p(x) = x^2 (x - 1)$$
We have :
$$p(-1) p(2) = (-2) \times 4 = -8 < 0$$
and $p$ has two (even number) roots $0$ and $1$.
Maybe you mean odd number of roots with multiplicity.